# How do I create an infinite hierarchal html tree in Rails 3.1?

Tags: url-rewriting, ruby-on-rails-3.1, navigation, hierarchical-data

I have a table called `Metrics` that is a self-referencing table.  Meaning it has a parent/child relationship with infinite children.

I have a route like:

```
match "/metrics/:id/children" => "metricchildren#index", :as => "metric_children"
```

The `metricchildren` contoller loads a metric's children and renders an index page.

That page looks something like (root parent called `Totals`):

```
Metric            Children?
----------------------------
Total Expense         YES
Total Labor           NO
```

Now, what I want to do is have the user click the `Total Expense` and then the URL would look something like:

```
http://example.com/metrics/42-totals/children/78-total-expense
```

`42` is the ID of the `Totals` metric, 78 is the ID of the `Total Expense` metric.  So when you drill down to `Total Expense` it would create a table as above and as you click the metrics, the urls grow like:

```
http://example.com/metrics/42-totals/children/78-total-expense/98-total-direct
http://example.com/metrics/42-totals/children/78-total-expense/98-total-direct/102-blah
```

etc...

Very similar to how Github works.  Even better would be the ability to not have to specify the ID's in the URL.

Any gems or ideas on how to do this?  I think I have an idea on how to do it but I don't want to reinvent that wheel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the "recursive routes", see [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353134/recursive-routes-in-rails). Short answer is, it's actually pretty easy with route globbing.

Now, I roll my own pretty permalinks, using a slug instead of the database ID, but I've heard great things about [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).